# phonegap - Linkedin API to authenticate users

Tags: api, oauth, cordova, linkedin-api

We are trying to develop an APP that uses Linkedin API to authenticate users. We are developing the APP with phonegap but have just managed to implement oauth through "PIN-based OAuth", as it’s a phonegap APP we don’t have a URL of callback where we can receive the Request Token.  (Twitter example: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/pin-based-authorization)

We would like to implement the traditional method (without pin) to skip an additional step in the APP. ¿Do you know the possible solutions? ¿Do you know anyone who could help us? ¿Any libraries for Android and IOS which can solve this problem?

Thank you so much!!